# grafico de varias variables con ggplot

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

tengo una base de datos como la siguiente:

| id | choice | pricec1 | pricec2 | princec3 | princec4 | princec5 | Income |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 8 | 20 |
| 1 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 10 | 20 |
| 1 | 1 | 9 | 8 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 20 |
| 1 | 4 | 9 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 9 | 20 |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 7 | 8 | 6 | 8 | 23 |
| 2 | 3 | 8 | 6 | 5 | 6 | 11 | 23 |
| 2 | 1 | 9 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 8 | 23 |
| 2 | 4 | 9 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 9 | 23 |

y me gustaría hacer un grafico con ggplot que me entregara boxplots de distribucion de precios para cada columna de precios, es decir, que hayan 5 boxplots uno para cada 'pricecn' (siendo n el número) existe alguna forma de hacer eso?

Answer (score 1):

Para crear gráficos en ggplot siempre es recomendable reducir el número de columnas agrupando aquellas que representan la misma unidad. Luego para diferenciar entre grupos, se puede ocupar una sola columna en vez de llamar a 5, por ejemplo.

Para este caso, la herramienta para agrupar columnas la incorpora la librería `tidyr` a través de `pivot_longer()`. Suponiendo que la tabla tiene por nombre `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,
                  Income,
                  choice),
               names_to = 'precio',
               values_to = 'valor') %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = precio,
             y = valor)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]